# Angualr Datatables: How to get sum of selected column values dynamically using javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

Have one table, and if we checkbox checked amount values automatically sum and displayed on top. Tried below code, its getting values but not getting exact sum values. Could you pls suggest the what is the issue..

```
checkboxCheckCount(info: any): void {
  var creditAmount = 0;
  $("#firstTable input:checked").each(function() {
    alert(info.index);
    if (info.index != "") {
      creditAmount += parseFloat(info.index);
    } else {
      creditAmount = creditAmount;
    }
  });
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-9xcnrg?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: my preferred method is to add change function to the inputs, so that every time you check/uncheck a  row the sum will be modified accordingly.

Comment: besides that, your mistake is that you are using info to sum at each iteration, but the info will be the same at each iteration since its the function input, and it's not depended from the current row in the loop

Comment: Yep, no, I saw Angular and jQuery together in the tags, and that's what I feared. You are doing the rookie mistake of mixing Angular and jQuery together. Just don't do that. These two really, really don't get along. Angular builds your HTML table from data, meaning _you have this data in your code_. Now you load and use another completely different library to _read_ the data from the HTML table built by Angular from data you already have, which is just reading a variable with a LOT of extra steps. Use Angular OR jQuery, not both together.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using `each` loop to iterate through your checked checkboxes you can use `$(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)")` this will give you `amount` column td value and then you can pass same to your `creditAmount`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  var creditAmount = 0;
  $("#firstTable input:checked").each(function() {
    //get td(amount column value)
    var values = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text()
    if (values != "") {
      creditAmount += parseFloat(values);
    } 
  });
  $("#idCheckBoxLabel").text(creditAmount);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>Count::<span id="idCheckBoxLabel"></span>
    <div>
      <div>
        <table datatable id="firstTable" [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
              <th>Amount</th>
              <th>First name</th>
              <th>Last name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Abc</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>Abc</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>Abc</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```